# Parsing/formatting api responses (nodejs/express)

Tags: node.js, express, response

I'm currently struggling with the size/format of response objects I get back from APIs.

I just often find it difficult to see nested objects of a response in my node terminal - keeping track of the indentation across what can be several hundred lines seems fairly unmanageable, to the point where I think I must be doing something wrong?

Are there any standard practices or helpful tools I can use? JSON.stringify() is *slightly* better, as at least I can see the entire response, but then it's just a wall of text, so sort of the opposite problem.

Apologies if this is obvious!

Comment: have you tries to specify the indentation with JSON.stringify ? (example `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)`). You can also copy you response and paste it in a JSON file, most IDEs will let you fold/unflod

Comment: I haven't no. Thanks, those are some good ideas

Comment: Asking for tool is a bit off-topic on SO, I'm voting to close this question since it will most likely get opinion-based answers.

Comment: I mean I'm happy to remove that bit? It was more because I didn't know whether *any* tool was a better approach.

Comment: Not sure if it's much help to others, but I certainly struggled to find the answer I was looking for - 'parsing APIs' tended to give answers about parsing large responses, and 'formatting APIs' gave answers about the format of REST responses. Having said that I might have just been phrasing it poorly

Comment: Yeah maybe formatting/parsing makes me think more of automated response transformation (changing format / structure) vs. reading the actual content. If you Google "json viewer" you should find plenty of suggestions, mostly online ones. But you can also paste your JSON in Chrome Dev tools console, use your IDE, some API tools (eg. postman) so you have a lot of options ! :)

Comment: (Closing is just to avoid an opinion war, nothing personal)

Comment: No that's fair enough - can I still view the question/answers despite it being closed? Has some useful things I'd like to refer to in the future. If not I'll make a note of them now

Comment: here's an [example of a closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230971/header-only-with-html-and-css), you can still comment (unless locked) but no more answer can be posted

Answer (score 0):

You can use util inspect from native node modules:

```
// Node.js syntax to demonstrate
// the util.inspect() method

// Importing util library
const util = require('util');

// Object
const nestedObject = {};
nestedObject.a = [nestedObject];
nestedObject.b = [['a', ['b']], 'b', 'c', 'd'];
nestedObject.b = {};
nestedObject.b.inner = nestedObject.b;
nestedObject.b.obj = nestedObject;

// Inspect by basic method
console.log("1.>", util.inspect(nestedObject));

// Random class
class geeksForGeeks { }

// Inspecting geeksForGeeks class
console.log("2.>", util.inspect(new geeksForGeeks()));

// Inspect by passing options to method
console.log("3.>", util.inspect(
        nestedObject, true, 0, false));

// Inspect by calling option name
console.log("4.>", util.inspect(nestedObject,
    showHidden = false, depth = 0, colorize = true));

// Inspect by passing in JSON format
console.log("5.>", util.inspect(nestedObject,
    { showHidden: false, depth: 0, colorize: true }));

// Inspect by directly calling inspect from 'util'
const { inspect } = require('util');

// Directly calling inspect method
// with single property
console.log("6.>", inspect(nestedObject),
        { colorize: true });

// Directly passing the JSON data
console.log("7.>", util.inspect([
    { name: "Amit", city: "Ayodhya" },
    { name: "Satyam", city: "Lucknow" },
    { name: "Sahai", city: "Lucknow" }],
    false, 3, true));

// Directly calling inspect method with single property
console.log("8.>", inspect(nestedObject), { depth: 0 });
```

Source: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-util-inspect-method/]

Comment: You can control the depth of objects (0 to infinite), colorize, etc... Better than pure console.log.